# Magento redirect /work160.com/

Tags: magento, redirect

I bought after the installation of magento template, uploading demo database and a few time later, the site URL / work160.com / domain name is directed. I delete and re-install again I have to. Magento is in line with our demo pages bring our own? This problem can be solved with a regulation or in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your magento is redirected on another website (that is how i understand your question), you can do those steps:

1. check your basic secure and unsecure URL configuration, there should be your server adress
2. if you cant not login to admin during redirect, fo to the database to table named core_config_data and make sure there is right set up web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url both will have to value http://www.something.ok/ the last "/" is important
3. Reindex / fush cached data (delete magento/var folder if you cannot pass admin)
4. Refresh data in your browser (or use another one / anonymous mode)

and ... thats all